# I can't see color in Material tab

Tags: color

I used to use blender a long time ago and now I started to use it again but I can't find the color option in the material. Is there anyone that knows how to fix it please? really appreciate it.
[image]
 I know that I can change the color where it says "Diffuse" but when I do that and want to add shader in the "Node editor" it doesn't show any output or input, so don't know how to do it.It would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me with this.

Comment: are you in Cycles Render?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the entire blender window, showing where you expected the missing color options to be.

Comment: No I am not in cycle render.

Comment: It doesn't let me add any screenshot!

Comment: An easy way to add a screenshot (if you're in Windows 7 or Windows 10 at least) is to press Win-key and type Snipping Tool and press enter. With that create a new snip, go to edit your post here, press Ctrl+G (insert image) and then just press Ctrl+V, which will paste the snipped image to the post.

Comment: Thank you so much mate! I just edit the post and explained more about what I meant.

Comment: It would be easier to understand the question if you add a screenshot / reference image of the option or a video from e.g. Youtube with mentioned functionality you're searching for (from e.g. another site or alike) at  as I don't understand what Color option do you want to find, whether you want to use Cycles render or not etc. So far you still use Blender Internal engine as shown in the answer

Answer (score 3):

## 1.

It might be that your panels are arranged in a non-default way.

If you use **Blender Render** or **Blender Internal** renderer (which is the default in a newly installed Blender):

- Find the **Diffuse panel** and change the color there

If you use **Cycles** renderer:

- Find the **Surface panel** and change the color there

[image]

---

## 2.

It also might be that you have created the material in **Blender Render** and then switched to **Cycles** renderer, or vice versa - which makes the material color slot disappear since the Blender Render and Cycles materials are not compatible (unless you know your way in complicated node setups).

In this case, easy way is to just remove the incompatible material from the minus button and add a new material by clicking **'New'**.

[image]

I hope this helps :)

If not, post a screenshot of your material panels to the first post, that would be helpful.

Comment: But this way when I got to Node Mode to add more stuff to my material, there is no shader (any small boxes) shown to be able to add or edit anything.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're experiencing if we can't see screenshots of what's happening. I really recommend some kind of tutorial video about shaders and nodes for learning some good working methods with them. Like this one (scroll a little bit down for the video): https://cgcookie.com/articles/pbr-in-blenders-viewport